# Beamer with Devnagari / Hindi

Tags: r, latex, knitr, beamer, rnw

I have a project with Hindi text which I am successfully able to knit when the document class is article or report or book. However, as soon as I make the class to be beamer, it starts giving me error. Any ideas if beamer works with Devnagari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, here is a simple and elegant solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Arial Unicode MS}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{Arial Unicode MS}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{प्राथमिकी}
मया \LaTeX  बहु रोचते।
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```